# Dots and boxes - JLabels disapearing

Tags: java, swing, jlabel

I'm trying to implement the game dots and boxes by using 3 JLabel arrays:

1. the dots for the game board.
2. the vertical lines
3. the horizontal lines

the ide is when you click using MouseInputAdapter to get the coordinates of the mouse the it should check if the coordinates of mouse point are in one of the labels of the verticals or horizontal lines. But when I run the program my JPanel is completly empty. And other times when I run it and it's not empty all the labels just vanish after I click.

```
package gameframes;

import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.LineBorder;
import javax.swing.event.MouseInputAdapter;
import java.awt.Color;

public class LinesAndBoxesFrame extends JFrame {

    JLabel[][] dots = new JLabel[8][8];
    JLabel[][] herizontalLines = new JLabel[8][7];
    JLabel[][] verticallLines = new JLabel[8][7];

    public LinesAndBoxesFrame(String title) {
        super(title);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setSize(620, 640);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setVisible(true);
        setLayout(null);
        
        JPanel p=new JPanel();
        p.setSize(600,600);
        add(p);
        for (int i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < dots.length; j++) {
                dots[i][j] = new JLabel();
                dots[i][j].setBounds(20 + i * (20 + 50), 20 + j * (20 + 50), 20, 20);
                dots[i][j].setOpaque(true);
                dots[i][j].setBackground(Color.red);
                p.add(dots[i][j]);
                p.repaint();
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < herizontalLines.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < herizontalLines[0].length; j++) {
                herizontalLines[i][j] = new JLabel();
                herizontalLines[i][j].setBounds(40 + j * (20 + 50), 20 + i * (20 + 50), 50, 20);
                herizontalLines[i][j].setOpaque(true);
                herizontalLines[i][j].setBackground(Color.green);
                herizontalLines[i][j].setVisible(false);
                p.add(herizontalLines[i][j]);
                p.repaint();
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < verticallLines.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < verticallLines[0].length; j++) {
                verticallLines[i][j] = new JLabel();
                verticallLines[i][j].setBounds(20 + i * (20 + 50), 40 + j * (20 + 50), 20, 50);
                verticallLines[i][j].setOpaque(true);
                verticallLines[i][j].setBackground(Color.green);
                verticallLines[i][j].setVisible(false);
                p.add(verticallLines[i][j]);
                p.repaint();
            }
        }
        p.addMouseListener(new MouseInputAdapter() {
            int count = 0;
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                int mX = e.getX();
                int mY = e.getY();
                System.out.println(mX);
                System.out.println(mY);
                boolean b = false;
                for (JLabel[] l : herizontalLines) {
                    for (JLabel l1 : l) {
                        b = checkBounds(l1, mX, mY);
                        if (b) {
                            l1.setVisible(true);
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
                if (!b) {
                    for (JLabel[] l : verticallLines) {
                        for (JLabel l1 : l) {
                            b = checkBounds(l1, mX, mY);
                            if (b) {
                                l1.setVisible(true);
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                System.out.println(b + " metod finished! " + count);
                p.revalidate();
                p.repaint();
                count++;
            }
        });

//      add(p);
//      repaint();
        p.revalidate();
        p.repaint();
    }

    public boolean checkBounds(JLabel l, int x, int y) {
        return (x >= l.getX() && x <= l.getX() + l.getWidth()) && (y >= l.getY() && y <= l.getY() + l.getHeight());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new LinesAndBoxesFrame("Dots and Boxes");
    }

}
```

Update:
I just needed to set the layout of my JPanel to null and that fixes it.

Comment: *"Update: I just needed to set the layout of my JPanel to null and that fixes it."* . . .  
Come back & read that again after you've debugged the 7th problem caused by using `null` layouts. You might then see the ROTFL side of it. **Sidebar:** most things mentioning a grid are well suited to using a `GridLayout`.

Comment: Oracle has a helpful tutorial, [Creating a GUI With Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html).  Skip the Learning Swing with the NetBeans IDE section.  It would be a lot easier to create a drawing `JPanel` and draw the dots and lines.  The [Performing Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) lesson will show you how.